# How can I enable Zip Archive on VPS CentOS 7 CyberPanel?

Tags: centos7, vps, php-ziparchive, cyber-panel

Some context I found this article: https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/tutorial-how-to-install-any-php-modules-using-pear-package-manager/37785

I ran the commands in my terminal. Once I got to this step:

```
./lsphp go-pear.phar
```

I got this on the screen

[PHP WARNING: Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD7ma.png)

My question is how can I resolve this and install the Zip Archive extension?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm not a developer so bare with me. I'm great a following along, but this is a bit out of my wheelhouse.